# How can I recursively fill an Idris character structure with dependent pairs using 'getChar'?

Tags: recursion, idris

can anyone help me with this..

This is the data structure that I am after:

```
example : (n : Nat ** Vect n (n1 : Nat ** Vect n1 Char))
example = (3 ** [(3 ** ['a', 'b', 'c']), (3 ** ['d', 'e', 'f']), (3 ** ['g', 'h', 'i'])])
```

I would like to read characters from STDIN and for every \n create a new vector with the characters from that line. An empty line ends recursion.

This would be the input for the above example:

```
abc\n
def\n
ghi\n
\n
```

I'm wondering if it is possible with one recursive function. Like this for whole strings:

```
read_vect : IO (len ** Vect len String)
read_vect = do x <- getLine
               if (x == "")
                  then pure (_ ** [])
                  else do (_ ** xs) <- read_vect
                          pure (_ ** x :: xs)
```

Many thanks in advance!
Jason.

Comment: Do you really want `(n : Nat ** Vect n (n1 : Nat ** Vect n1 Char))` and not `(n : Nat ** n1 : Nat ** Vect n (Vect n1 Nat))`? Former allows `example = (2 ** [(2 ** ['f', 'o']), (1 ** ['o'])])`, that I wouldn't call a matrix.

Comment: Yes I really want `(n : Nat ** Vect n (n1 : Nat ** Vect n1 Char))`. I made a mistake by using the word 'matrix'. I replaced it with the word 'structure' in the question title. I would like to iterate over the characters line by line character by character. But the lines all have different lengths. So indeed this is not a matrix. If it actually was for a matrix your answer looks very nice! I'm really sorry for the confusion but can you please do another suggestion?

Comment: I added another solution. :-) I hope `getChar` is not mandatory? That would make it more complex …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, `getLine`: not wanting an actual matrix, this is quite straight forward:

```
read_structure : IO (k : Nat ** Vect k (l : Nat ** Vect l Char))
read_structure = do str <- getLine
                    let chrs = unpack str
                    let x = fromList chrs
                    if length chrs == 0
                       then pure (_ ** [])
                       else do (_ ** xs) <- read_structure
                               pure (_ ** (_ ** x) :: xs)
```

Idris can infer the most things (and `**` binds stronger than `::`), but to make it clear, the verbose version would be :

```
                       then pure (0 ** [])
                       else do (n ** xs) <- read_structure
                               pure ((S n) ** ((length chrs ** x) :: xs))
```

Edit, `getChar`: If you actually want to go with a recursion with `getChar`, the following is a version that, when wrapped with `read_list True`, will get you a `List (List Char)`. The `break` parameter is to find out, if there has been two `'\n'` in a row.

```
read_list : Bool -> IO (List (List Char))
read_list break = do chr <- getChar
                     if chr == '\n'
                        then if break
                                then pure []
                                else do rest <- read_list True
                                        pure ([] :: rest)
                        else do rest <- read_list False
                                case rest of
                                     x :: xs => pure ((chr :: x) :: xs)
                                     Nil => pure ([chr] :: Nil)
```

To get this work with `k : Nat ** Vect k (l : Nat ** Vect l Char)`, you just need to throw in some `(_ ** xs)`:

```
read_vects : Bool -> IO (k : Nat ** Vect k (l : Nat ** Vect l Char))
read_vects break = do chr <- getChar
                      if chr == '\n'
                        then if break
                                then pure (_ ** [])
                                else do (_ ** rest) <- read_vects True
                                        pure (_ ** (_ ** []) :: rest)
                        else do (_ ** rest) <- read_vects False
                                case rest of
                                     (_ ** x) :: xs => pure (_ ** (_ ** (chr :: x)) :: xs)
                                     Nil => pure (_ ** (_ ** [chr]) :: Nil)
```

The `List` version is definitely more readable, and as pointed out by Cactus, `List a` is pretty much equivalent to `k ** Vect k a`. So you may parse it first and then convert in to `Vect`s.

Comment: Xash, I'm still testing but it seems fast enough like this. Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your type in `example` is isomorphic to just `List (List Char)`, since you can do

```
listToVect : List a -> (n : Nat ** Vect n a)
listToVect xs = (length xs ** fromList xs)

vectToList : (n : Nat ** Vect n a) -> List a
vectToList (_ ** xs) = toList xs
```

so we can just write it in terms of `List`:

```
lines : List Char -> List (List Char)
lines = foldr step []
  where
    step : Char -> List (List Char) -> List (List Char)
    step '\n' ls = [] :: ls
    step c [] = [[c]]
    step c (l::ls) = (c::l) :: ls

lines' : String -> (n : Nat ** Vect n (n' : Nat ** Vect n' Char))
lines' = listToVect . map listToVect . lines . unpack
```

**However, I don't believe this is what you want.**

A matrix of characters is not `List (List Char)`, it's a `Vect n (Vect m Char)` for some fixed `n` and `m`, since the whole point of it being a matrix is that all the rows are the same length.

We can implement it as

```
Matrix : Nat -> Nat -> Type -> Type
Matrix n m a = Vect n (Vect m a)
```

and then write something that parses a matrix of a given size:

```
parseLine : (m : Nat) -> List Char -> Maybe (Vect m Char, List Char)
parseLine Z ('\n'::cs) = Just ([], cs)
parseLine (S m) (c :: cs) = map (\(l, cs') => (c::l, cs')) $ parseLine m cs
parseLine _ _ = Nothing

parseMatrix' : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> List Char -> Maybe (Matrix n m Char, List Char)
parseMatrix' Z m ['\n'] = Just ([], [])
parseMatrix' (S n) m cs = case parseLine m cs of
  Nothing => Nothing
  Just (l, cs') => case parseMatrix' n m cs' of
    Nothing => Nothing
    Just (ls, cs'') => Just (l::ls, cs'')
parseMatrix' _ _ _ = Nothing

parseMatrix : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> String -> Maybe (Matrix n m Char)
parseMatrix n m = map fst . parseMatrix' n m . unpack
```

This is still not quite what you want, since `n` and `m` are predetermined instead of looking at the input; so maybe we should go with

```
SomeMatrix : Type -> Type
SomeMatrix a = (n ** (m ** Matrix n m a))
```

leading to

```
parseSomeMatrix : String -> Maybe (SomeMatrix Char)
parseSomeMatrix cs = case map unpack (lines cs) of
    l::ls => parseFrom l ls
    [] => Just (0 ** (0 ** []))
  where
    parseFrom : List Char -> List (List Char) -> Maybe (SomeMatrix Char)
    parseFrom cs ls = map (\vs => (length vs ** (m ** fromList vs))) (parseInto ls)
      where
        m : Nat
        m = length cs

        parseInto : List (List Char) -> Maybe (List (Vect m Char))
        parseInto [] = Just []
        parseInto (l :: ls) with (decEq (length l) m)
          | Yes p = map (\vs => (replace {P = \m => Vect m Char} p (fromList l)) :: vs) (parseInto ls)
          | No _ = Nothing
```